# how to query two tables using mysql conditions

Tags: mysql

Query two tables using mysql conditions

How can I get specific query if I will use some query conditions, for example I have table:

TableA:

```
column1
  row1111
  row2222
  row3333
  row4444
```

TableB:

```
 column1
  rowAAAA
  rowBBBB
  rowCCCC
  rowDDDD
```

Is it possible if I want to gave a condition to check the selected column ins null or empty. Here is my pseudo code:

```
if any column in Table A query is null, I will use query to TableB
else query to TableA
```

Any suggestion or comments is a big help!, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify how you're deciding which value from TableB you want if you encounter a `null` value in TableA? It's possible `coalesce()` may be helpful depending upon what you want to do.

Comment: sorry about my question, but my main point here is validation in the tableA. My logic is query specific col in table A. If it returns empty I will query the Table B else I will use Table A because it is not empty. Im just wondering if it is possible in query so that I will not use coding from my application.

Comment: What are you searching for from `tableA` or from `tableB`? Please post the schema of these two tables.

Comment: if there is no return or null or emplty in col1 in Table A use to query the Table B...... Else just use to query Table A

Comment: For your above sample data your expected query will return all the values under `column1` from `table_A`?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two tables? Are they related to another table? This looks like something that's done in language translation: use the translation in language A, but if it doesn't exist use language B.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may work for you:

```
SELECT `value` FROM (
 SELECT 'a' as `source`, a.* from tableA a
 UNION
 SELECT 'b' as `source`, b.* from tableB b) j
WHERE `source` = IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA 
                     WHERE `value` IS null)>0,'b','a');
```

#### Explanation

We're merging the full dataset via `UNION`, identifying the source of each row.  Then in the `WHERE` clause, we're picking from either one table or the other depending upon whether there are `NULL` values detected within tableA.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55e52e/1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get what you are trying.

But doing it from `two different tables` would slow it down.

Combine `both columns` in a same table and you can get the results by **using below query**

```
select coalesce(column1,column2) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` and `NOT EXISTS` to accomplish this

RETURN value from second query if the first query returns NULL ELSE return result from first query

```
SELECT 
colA
FROM table_A

UNION 

SELECT colB
FROM table_b
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT colA from table_a
)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2866e/2/0).